# Rolling Status from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+
| area | locale |    date    |  end date  | i | t | o |
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-03-01 | 2001-04-01 | 1 |   |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-04-01 | 2001-05-01 | 1 |   |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-01 | 1 |   |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-06-01 | 2001-07-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-07-01 | 2001-08-01 |   |   | 1 |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-08-01 | 2001-09-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-09-01 | 2001-05-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-10-01 | 2001-11-01 |   | 1 |   |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-11-01 | 2001-12-01 |   |   | 1 |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-12-01 |            |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def25  | 2001-03-01 | 2001-04-01 |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def25  | 2001-04-01 | 2001-05-01 |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def25  | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-01 |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def25  | 2001-06-01 | 2001-07-01 |   | 1 |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-07-01 | 2001-08-01 |   | 1 |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-08-01 | 2001-09-01 | 1 |   |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-09-01 | 2001-05-01 | 1 |   |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-10-01 | 2001-11-01 |   | 1 |   |
| def  | def25  | 2001-11-01 | 2001-12-01 |   |   | 1 |
| def  | def25  | 2001-12-01 |            |   |   | 1 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+
```

Here is the data table sample that I am working with.  What I am attempting to do is a status column added on here.  The status column is a bit tricky though and here is the criteria:

1. If any 2 periods of time are the same i/t/o then they get their associated status (let's say R/Y/G)
2. If you have two different statuses you choose "best"

Example Output:

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+--------+
| area | locale |    date    |  end date  | i | t | o | Status |
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+--------+
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-03-01 | 2001-04-01 | 1 |   |   |  NONE  |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-04-01 | 2001-05-01 | 1 |   |   |  R     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-01 | 1 |   |   |  R     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-06-01 | 2001-07-01 |   | 1 |   |  Y     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-07-01 | 2001-08-01 |   |   | 1 |  G     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-08-01 | 2001-09-01 |   | 1 |   |  G     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-09-01 | 2001-05-01 |   | 1 |   |  Y     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-10-01 | 2001-11-01 |   | 1 |   |  Y     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-11-01 | 2001-12-01 |   |   | 1 |  G     |
| abc  | abc25  | 2001-12-01 |            |   |   | 1 |  G     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-03-01 | 2001-04-01 |   |   | 1 |  NONE  |
| def  | def25  | 2001-04-01 | 2001-05-01 |   |   | 1 |  G     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-05-01 | 2001-06-01 |   |   | 1 |  G     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-06-01 | 2001-07-01 |   | 1 |   |  G     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-07-01 | 2001-08-01 |   | 1 |   |  Y     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-08-01 | 2001-09-01 | 1 |   |   |  Y     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-09-01 | 2001-05-01 | 1 |   |   |  R     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-10-01 | 2001-11-01 |   | 1 |   |  Y     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-11-01 | 2001-12-01 |   |   | 1 |  G     |
| def  | def25  | 2001-12-01 |            |   |   | 1 |  G     |
+------+--------+------------+------------+---+---+---+--------+
```

Now I looked up pandas rolling, but that might not be the best approach; I tried the following:

```
df.groupby('locale')['o'].rolling(2).sum()
```

which works on it's own, but I can't seem to create a column out of it so I can say if that == 2 then it is whatever status.  I also tried to just use this in an `if` statement:

```
if df.groupby('locale')['o'].rolling(2).sum() == 2.0 : 
    df['locale_status'] = 'Green'
```

this gives an error about the truth value of a series

I also tried :

```
if df.groupby('locale')['o'] == df.groupby('locale')['o'].shift() : df['test'] = 'Green'
```

This results in an invalid type comparison.

Comment: Can you please explain better what you mean with `If you have two different statuses you choose "best"`

Comment: yea sorry R = Red Y= Yellow G= Green, so best is G, then Y, Then R so if you have to choose between R and Y you choose Y, same with Y and G and R and G

Comment: Just to get clear the order, 1st: G, 2nd: Y, 3rd:R ? This seems to differ with what you say later

Comment: if you look at the sample output, which I did have an error early on and is now fixed, and look at row 3,4,5.  So in Row 3 we have an R.  When we look to decide if row 4 should be a R as well it should not, it should now be a Y because you don't have a match in the previous row.  So you take the best (Y).  Then in Row 5 we look at the previous, no match, but we are now in G and not Y.  Essentially you can only get worse if you go two months in a row, but you can get better with only 1 month.

Comment: why is there a NONE in the middle?

Comment: Okay got it now, there were some errors

Comment: there's still a NONE in the middle that should be a G, if I understand your rules correctly

Comment: Btw could you please share instead the result of `print(df)`? Or if anyone can tell me a simple way to read this

Comment: @yatu, I copied it and used `df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='|', engine='python')`, `df=df.iloc[1:-1,1:-1]`, and `df=df.rename(columns={ ' i ':'i',' t ':'t',' o ':'o',})`

Comment: Awesome, thx @JoshFriedlander

Comment: There is a none because it is partitioned it by locale.  This is a building and each building doesn't apply to the other.  Notice DEF and ABC; I made an assumption that when I showed my attempts with the group by locale it would indicate I am doing this within a partition.  I should have made that clear.

Comment: no, I cannot share the raw data.  It is not public.

Comment: @Shenanigator oh, I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this problem lends itself to vectorization/Pandas efficiency, but I'd love to be proven wrong by one of the ninjas on here. My solution involves some prep from `pd.read_clipboard()` you probably don't need.

Basically I replaced blanks with 0, used `idxmax` to get the 'current' letter, and found if there's a streak. I then looped through the rows to find the 'best' or 'streak', inside a `groupby`.

```
#data cleaning - from clipboard, prob irrelevant to OP
df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='|', engine='python', header=1)
df=df.reset_index().iloc[1:-1,1:-1]
df=df.rename(columns={ ' i ':'i',' t ':'t',' o ':'o',})
df=df.drop('Unnamed: 0',1)
df=df.replace('   ', 0)

df['current'] = df[['i','t','o']].astype(int).idxmax(1)
df['streak'] = df['current'] == df['current'].shift(1)

weights = {'i':0, 't':1, 'o':2}
results = []
for val in df[' area '].unique():
    temp = df.loc[df.groupby(' area ').groups[val]].reset_index(drop=True)
    winner = []
    for idx, row in temp.iterrows():
        if idx == 0:
            winner.append(np.nan)
        else:
            current = row['current']
            if row['streak']:
                winner.append(current)
            else:
                last = temp.loc[idx-1, 'current']
                if weights[last] > weights[current]:
                    winner.append(last)
                else:
                    winner.append(current)
    temp['winner'] = winner
    results.append(temp)

res = pd.concat(results)
res['winner'] = res['winner'].map({'i':'R','t':'Y','o':'G'})
```

Comment: I just tested this and I never get a R even when it should be R.  I am trying to look at why.

Comment: Found it, I made a typo in translation of your code to my actual data.

Comment: I am probably going to have to change the first line in each to be whatever it starts as because now I am being told we have to know first line.  I am still playing with how to make a graph out of this to fit the question being asked.

Comment: Well this just got a lot worse for me.  I am going to have to do roll-ups now.  I'll probably post a question on that later.  essentially I have to do total periods of R/Y/G so that is going to require looking at min/max dates during the R/Y/G periods.  Back to the drawing board

Comment: Sorry to hear that - feel free to post again if you have another question

Comment: Will do, what they essentially want is to group this by the R/Y/G and get MIN(date) and MAX(end_date) so they can have a total days in the period.